# Запуск приложения без консоли

Tags: bat, java

Доброго времени суток! Такая проблема - для запуска приложения написал bat файл -

```
start \B javaw -jar app.jar
```

Проблема в том, что у пользователей, как правило, путь к javaw не прописан, а если написать вместо javaw java, то консоль не убирается. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если я правильно понял то у вас рядом с AppName.jar лежит BatName.bat и оба файла лежат не на "С:\", а скажем на "H:\", если да то у вас просто не может найти java и javaw, так как ищет от пользователя а не от root потому он и не ищет в "C:\Windows\System32" где они лежат, если бы был прописан path(путь до JRE/JDK), то поискал бы и там, но он не прописан.

это можно вылечить так :

можно прописать в path "путь до JRE/JDK" или "C:\Windows\System32"

можно ассоциировать расширение "*.jar" с java или javaw и соответственно будет запускаться вообще без батника...

можно запускать батник от имени root(администратор-система) и через "%~dp0%" запускать ваш jar

можно упаковать весь jar'ник (а так же JRE/JDK, и ещё чего-нибудь) в *.exe который будет всё проверять и настраивать (например за вас пропишет path и\или ассоциирует ".jar"), он же сможет установить JRE/JDK если их не будет на компе пользователя.

p.s. так как в винде два разных понятия именуют одним словом (администратор-система, администратор-пользователь) я соответственно их называю root и админ

Answer (score 0):

Вы о чём? `javaw` находится в той же директории, что и `java`, а именно — в директории `bin` установленной JRE. Если у пользователя эта директория добавлена в `PATH`, то `javaw` без проблем запустится. Если же нет, то и `java` не будет найдена.

Comment: Просто при запуске вылетело сообщение, что javaw не найден, хотя java там точно установлена